# Locking MacBook with shortcut breaks Safari's search function

Tags: macos, safari

When I lock my MacBook with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> while Safari is open and unlock it, Safari's search function becomes broken. Before I lock my laptop, I can just type something in the url bar and Safari automatically searches it on Google. But after I unlock it, when I write something in the url bar, let's say "Hello World", after I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it automatically turns into "Hello%20World" and it just errors out. Why is this happening? The same thing doesn't happen when I lock from the Apple Menu.

macOS Version: 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

Safari version: 11.1.2 (13605.3.8)

Comment: Please update the question to include version of macOS and Safari.

Comment: [I can't make this an answer because it's far too vague]... I've seen this happen, but I've always put it down to "lag"... normally if i type 'map' then I get google maps etc. If I'm a bit too quick for it, I get a search for 'map' or for a more complex term I get a 'failed url' or 'bad search' like hello%20world as you note. I think it's some kind of 'slowdown' not an absolute fail. Maybe test my theory & let us know... watch the URL bar as you type - does it 'fix' itself if you wait an extra second or two?

Comment: btw I rarely lock my Mac, though it will lock itself after an hour away - but I did test to see if that was directly affecting it... it isn't.